# Escribir texto sobre archivo

Tags: c#

Buen dia.
Estoy realizando una app de escritorio para escribir texto en unos archivos `.ini`

Hecho pruebas para leerlos tanto `.txt` como `.ini`. Funciona a la perfección y escribir sobre archivos `.txt` funciona super bien, normal, sin errores. Pero el problema es al escribir sobre archivos `.ini` no me funciona y el error que me indica es el siguiente:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Acceso denegado a la ruta de acceso 'C:\Users\angela\Documents\fields.ini'.
   en System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   en System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   en System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   en System.IO.StreamWriter.CreateFile(String path, Boolean append, Boolean checkHost)
   en System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)
   en System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding)
   en System.IO.File.AppendAllLines(String path, IEnumerable`1 contents)
   en WindowsFormsApp1.Form1.btnsumar_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) en C:\Users\angela\Documents\pr\AppOne\WindowsFormsApp1\Form1.cs:línea 51
```

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
 // Leer los archivos en la ruta
            int counter = 0;
            string line;
            System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\Users\angela\Documents\fields.ini");

            // Lectura de las lineas
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(line); 
                lblresultado.Text = line;

                counter++;
            }

            file.Close();
            System.Console.ReadLine();


            // Escribir en archivos
            // En archivos txt funciona pero en el .ini NO funciona
            string path = @"C:\Users\angela\Documents\fields.ini";
            string texto = "Ha llegado hasta linea X";

            File.AppendAllLines(path, new String[] { texto });
```

Comment: segun tu error dice que acceso denegado a tu ruta, pueden verificar en permisos de tu carpeta y habilitar los necesarios.

Comment: Puede ser su antivirus.

Comment: Puede ser el antivirus, o Windows Defender que no deje cambiar el contenido de las carpetas en tus documentos, o permisos... procura no trabajar con cosas allá adentro en `C:/Users/tu-usuario`, pues es una ruta muy controlada por Windows... usa una nueva carpeta con permisos correctos (`c:/Workspace` o algo así).

Answer (score 1):

Se puede deber a que no tiene permiso para acceder a la ruta por el usuario o el antivirus, primero asegurar que el usuario tenga permiso sobre la ruta y que el antivirus no este bloqueando la ejecución detenlo y prueba.
También puedes habilitar que el proyecto se ejecute como administrador; crear un archivo app.manifest en el proyecto

Modifica el archivo añade `<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />`

Esa sección queda de la siguiente forma

```
<trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />        
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
</trustInfo>
```